# Ctrl select multiple items and access via form post

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I have a form which has a list of days shown - the user clicks on a day and I use jQuery to populate a hidden field with the value which I can then reference in the post array.

I now would like to allow users to select more than one item by using Ctrl+Click and then be able to access all the selected options in the post array but am not sure how to go about it?

I have figured out how to allow selecting multiple items but I cant figure out how to access this via post as my current code only contains the last clicked item in the hidden field.

Here is what I am using currently:

```
var multiple = false;
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  multiple = e.ctrlKey;
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '[name="day"]', function () {
        if (multiple) {
            $('[name="date"]').val($(this).text());
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('[name="day"]').removeClass('selected');
            $('[name="date"]').val($(this).text());
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z44Lvs48/1/

Comment: Just FYI your code causes issues on OSX where CTRL+click opens the context menu.

Comment: Good spot, PC user here so didn't see that one - this code is not live yet so thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using `$('[name="date"]').val($(this).text());`, which means you *replace* the value in the input every time a date is clicked.

Instead, you should *append* to the input and separate each value with, for example, a comma.

So change:

```
$('[name="date"]').val($(this).text());
```

to:

```
$('[name="date"]').val($('[name="date"]').val() + ',' + $(this).text());
```

The extra `$('[name="date"]').val()` just means to add to the current value.

I've removed the 'hidden' for the input in the example so you can see what I mean ([updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/z44Lvs48/2/)):

```js
var multiple = false;
$(document).on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  multiple = e.ctrlKey;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '[name="day"]', function() {
    if (multiple) {
      $('[name="date"]').val($('[name="date"]').val() + ',' + $(this).text());
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    } else {
      $('[name="day"]').removeClass('selected');
      $('[name="date"]').val($(this).text());
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.base {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="date">

<br>
<span id="days_disp"><div name="day" class="base wd selected"><span>Mon</span>
<br>05/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base wd"><span>Tue</span>
  <br>06/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base wd"><span>Wed</span>
  <br>07/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base wd"><span>Thu</span>
  <br>08/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base wd"><span>Fri</span>
  <br>09/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base nwd"><span>Sat</span>
  <br>10/10/2015</div>
<div name="day" class="base nwd"><span>Sun</span>
  <br>11/10/2015</div>
</span>
```

You can then access the hidden input's value (`val()`) and use `.split(',')` (to split at each comma) to form an array of dates with which you can work on to do whatever you want to do.